# Django admin, custom view error : invalid literal for int() with base 10

Tags: django, django-admin, django-templates, django-urls

I'm trying to make a custom view in Django admin. I'm reading from this site, [Simple Django Admin Preview](http://latherrinserepeat.org/2008/7/28/stupid-simple-django-admin-previews/), but I have a problem:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '13/preview'
```

Here is my url.py:

```
url(r'^admin/diligencias/diligencia/(?P<object_id>\d+)/preview/$','preview'),
```

Here is my view.py:

```
@staff_member_required
def preview(request, object_id):
   return object_detail(request, object_id=object_id,queryset=Diligencia.objects.all(), template_object_name = 'diligencia', )
```

What does this error mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The request isn't being picked up by that URLconf, but by the default admin view, which expects everything after the app/model to be the integer value of the primary key.

You may need to move your URL higher in the list of URLs, so that it comes before the one that includes the admin urls.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, now i have a new one error:

Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "/home/iosira05/webapps/django/lib/python2.5/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 92, in get_response
   response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Answer (score 1):

What Gabriel says is incorrect.  My guess is the problem is that your view is *after* the other admin views in the URLConf, therefore this URL gets caught by a catchall one the Django amdin uses the "13/preview" could be a valid PK, therefore you should move this URL above the other admin ones.

Answer (score -2):

```js
def importnum():
    n1 = int(raw_input ("enter 1st number?"))
    n2 = int(raw_input ("enter 1st number?"))
    return n1+n2

def main():
    n3=importnum()
    print n3*1/2
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```